# How to get correct values ​when pressing the number keys on the right side

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to get correct values ​​when pressing the number keys on the right side. I am handling the onKeyDown event to get the key that the user enters. Here is an example:

```
    const MyComponent: React.FC = () => {

  const onKeyDownHandle =(event: any)=> {
    console.log(event.key)
  }

  return <input type="text" onKeyDown={onKeyDownHandle}/>


}
```

The problem is that when I type the number 1 (Of the keys on the right side of the keyboard) I get "End", and when I use the numbers above the letters I get "1" as a result. Any ideas ?

Comment: Turn on NumLock?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a hardware issues instead of a software one. The keyboard is responsible for what values (keys) are input to the computer. Keyboards will often times double up on key values using some other key to activate the alternative value (shift, FN, num lock). This changes what values (key) the keyboard inputs to the computer.

You can't really try to accommodate for both possible key values (1 or End) since, on most keyboards, the 5 does not have a value. As a way around this you can give your users an alert reminding them to ensure num lock is turned on.